# svn without local copy

Tags: svn, version-control, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm in this kind of situation: i'm working with a remote developer on a cakephp website.

He works on a local copy (php etc..) and updates a staging server. I usually do directly the edits (mainly css and text changes) on the remote staging server because I can't run a local copy of the website. What do you suggest for a SVN environment without running a local copy on my machine?

I had setup an account with Beanstalk to do 1-click deploy from staging to production and automatic ftp upload of changed files on staging server when the developer does the commit.

My question is, what could I do to commit my changes as I'm modifying directly the files on remote staging server?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote development server could be showing a working-copy.
As you work there, you can write the *svn ci* command whenever you want to commit a new version.
You also could programme a cronjob to refresh the server working-copy to update to your partner's changes.

Comment: I'm starting to think that if I could run a local copy would be the best. Local files editing > svn commit > automatic ftp (on commit) of changed files from repository to staging server (via Beanstalk). When both parts are happy with the release in staging server, we can finally deploy to production server.

If I understood, to do the same without a local working copy I need a 3rd remote server i.e. a dev-server where I modify the files and then > commit to staging > ftp to production. Right?

Comment: mmm... your 1-click script could just make the svn ci in the staging (where you're developing) and svn co in the production box.
Have you ssh access to both?
By the way, are you using Beanstalk just a svn repository? or you have shell access?